# XUnit Test Orderer vs Parallel

Tags: xunit, xunit2

I have a suite of system tests that are driven by XUnit (2.x).  These run against a freshly deployed set of microservices.

(I know many feel that tests shouldn't have an order dependency and should be independent, but what we have works well as a complete suite to run after every deployment).

We need an ordering, as there is some initial tests that act as tests *and* as setup steps against the services.  These are necessary before the other tests can run.  One thing I could do is move the setup steps into an Assembly Fixture.  However, I do value them being in test-cases themselves.

We are using Xunit.extensions.ordering to enforce the order, but the tests currently run sequentially.

I'd like to introduce parallelism for the later tests, like the following:-

Non-Parallel tests (initial setup)

- TestClass 1 [Order(1)]
- TestClass 2 [Order(2)]
- TestClass 3 [Order(3)]

Then, in Parallel

[Order(4)]

- TestClass4, TestClass5, TestClass6 ....

My first attempt at enabling parallelisation in XUnit appears to show that the order is no longer respected (by removing the CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true) assembly attribute).  This appears to disable any ordering.

I can see that there is a way to disable parallel running for a specific collection, using
[CollectionDefinition(DisableParallelization = true)]

**However, the XUnit docs say that this results in parallel-enabled tests running first, then sequential ones after.   I'd need the opposite of this.**

Is this possible to do?